# Calculate cumul Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to calculate cumulative interest in VBA but i want to use code Vba,
the function is Range("L12").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-1]"

Comment: You seem new to Stackoverflow (or SO), I would suggest you to read [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to better grasp the format of questions on the website. Is a VBA code necessary for your question ? It is not very clear, because an Excel formula seems sufficient.

Comment: Yes I need a code-vba, because I work on userform and I need automatic calculations every time I do a filtering

Comment: I know how to do it in excel but I do not know how to do it in vba code

Comment: Ok, first, **edit your question to be clearer**, like "Calculating a sum in a dynamic column in VBA", else it will be downvoted, or worse, deleted, I will also help you with the formating. On SO, it is necessary to **show what you have done so far**, we are not able to give you a code out of the blue that will solve your particular problem. What have you **found on the internet** to solve your problem for example.

Comment: It is if possible to help me, really I need it

Comment: Ok, now, you should explain, in the question, why you cannot do it in Excel, why the VBA code is necessayr and how you would think it would work, do you know how to write some basic VBA code ? Do you know how to record macros ? I cannot give you a wall of code if I do not understand broadly the problem.

Comment: I am a beginner in Excel-vba, but my goal is to realize a mini project, I realized add, edit and delete data using the userform, I used macros, and now I'm in the dashboard part, Then I have a filtering by critere, and each filtering that I make,  I want to calculate pareto , cumulates of each line and  to see in a graph and all that in a userform

Comment: You really need VBA? It seems that just writting `=L12+K13` in L13 and dragging down you can accomplish what you want.

Comment: I use this code but in the cell take

Comment: I use this code but take this  result  >  #NAME? Sub cumule()

Dim K As Integer

k11 = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
Cells(k11 + 1, "L").Formula = "=SUM(l11:l" & K & ")"

End Sub

Comment: As suggested by @PierreChevallier, please edit your question again to contain all of those useful information in it, e.g. the code you have just pasted. If you provide those information in the comments, it's really hard to read and most people won't even see it and will downvote your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know what do you want exactly, but this might help you... With the first line you get the row number of the last cell that contains data in the 11th column (K). Then you do the same calculations you suggested but in VBA code.

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

Range("L11") = Range("K11").Value
Range("L12").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+RC[-1]"
Range("L12").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L12:L" & LastRow & "")
```

As other users said, you should do some research on your own, see how to **record macros** and you will be able to code everything you are able to do on excel.